# How do you reference a C# class library from a Win8 Javascript metro application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

When I try the standard way it complains of an unsupported reference and I can't seem to use any of my classes.

Comment: What sort of C# class library is this?  Does it target .NETCore?  Does it produce a .winmd?

Comment: To be more specific, when creating the class library project, make sure that you use the template under "Windows Metro style" rather than just "Windows" - that way you'll get the .winmd and everything else that's necessary for this to work. You can't reference a vanilla class library project that way.

Comment: In addition to the Metro specific class library type, you can also create a Portable Library project that can be used across Metro and standard .NET (also supports Silverlight and WP7) but only allows the subset of functionality that's common across the platforms you pick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a Windows Runtime component by creating a class library from the "Visual C#" -> "Windows Metro Style" -> "Class Library" template. Then in the properties for that class library project you need to mark the output type as "WinMD File"

Better instructions can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077(v=vs.110).aspx

This isn't stated in the documentation and is probably just a bug with the Windows 8 Consumer Preview and the Visual Studio 11 Beta but be sure not to include a period in the name of the project you're referencing. For instance, I was working on a Car application so I made an assembly named "Car.Business". The application would always crash with a blank startup screen whenever I tried to reference this. If on the other hand I just used "Business" as the name of the assembly then the application would work fine.