# Portable Class Library for JS Metro Style project

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

I was developing a Portable Class Library that targets .Net 4.5, Metro App, WP7.
When I wanted to reference it from a JavaScript Metro Style project, an error occured.

> Confirm unsupported reference(s).
>   One or more of the selected items is not a valid reference for this type of projects.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tWc4.png

Otherwise, it works fine with a C# Metro Style project.

Comment: What error? Please provide a bit more information.

Comment: @DanielA.White I can't reference a PCL project from JS Metro Style Project.

Comment: @Sascha post was edited.

Comment: @medouederni Robert Levy's answer is correct and you screenshot seconds it. Thanks for the update. therefore +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portable Class Libraries can be referenced from .NET apps for different platforms.  But that's different from writing a .NET library that can be called from JS (or other languages like C++) via WinRT.  For that, you'll need to compile your library into a '.winmd' which adds a whole bunch of fun constraints.  Take a look at this question for some pointers: [How do you reference a C# class library from a Win8 Javascript metro application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650654/how-do-you-reference-a-c-sharp-class-library-from-a-win8-javascript-metro-applic)

Comment: The output type is now called "Windows Runtime Component" instead of "WinMD File".